# ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"educations"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

I am running tests, on a controller `spec/controllers/educations_controller_spec.rb`, with RSpec.

Even in my most basic test for get `:index` I am getting the error:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"educations"}
```

I have seen posts about show/edit/update where an id is required, but I don't think an id should be necessary for an index action.

In spec/controllers/educations_controller_spec.rb:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe EducationsController, type: :controller do
  describe 'GET #index' do
    it "renders the :index template" do
      get :index
      expect(response).to render_template :index
    end
  end
end
```

My routes file includes this index action:

```
resources :applications, only: [:index, :new, :show, :create, :edit, :update] do
    resources :educations, only: [:index, :new, :create, :edit, :update]
    resources :montessori_trainings, only: [:index, :new, :create, :edit, :update]
    resources :work_experiences, only: [:index, :new, :create, :edit, :update]
    resources :references, only: [:index, :new, :create, :edit, :update]
    resources :documents, only: [:index, :new, :create, :edit, :update]
end
```

Do you think it has something to do with the education routes being nested inside the applications routes?

I am using Devise. Could there be a conflict there?

Thanks for any and all advice!

Comment: is the controller already made, and an index action listed on it?

Comment: Does `GET /educations` appears if you run `rake routes`?

Answer (score 4):

It *exactly* has to do with the education routes being nested inside the applications routes. If you `rake routes`, you'll see (for educations):

```
      application_educations GET    /applications/:application_id/educations(.:format)                    educations#index
                             POST   /applications/:application_id/educations(.:format)                    educations#create
   new_application_education GET    /applications/:application_id/educations/new(.:format)                educations#new
  edit_application_education GET    /applications/:application_id/educations/:id/edit(.:format)           educations#edit
       application_education PATCH  /applications/:application_id/educations/:id(.:format)                educations#update
                             PUT    /applications/:application_id/educations/:id(.:format)                educations#update
```

So, your educations routes are expecting `application_id`.

You'll either need to: (1) include an `@application` instance in your `application_educations_path` or (2) un-nest the routes.

Comment: Thanks @jvillian! This definitely helped me get the test to work. For anyone following, the next road-block I hit was signing in with Devise: I added => sign_in create(:user)   <= to my educations_controller_spec.rb and it stopped me from being redirected to a log-in page and actually took me to the index

Comment: Great. Feel free to upvote or accept as you see fit.

Comment: I did upvote you, but I am super new so it doesn't show. (apparently it is recorded though?) @jvillian